# How to fix the size of a div but keep it responsive

Tags: html, css, list, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to make a container (a box) who contain infos and I want to fix the size but I want to make it responsive. Look this image to understand a bit better what I'm trying to do:

So that's permitted:
[image]
Same for the moment it's ok:
[image]
WRONG it should block the size 
[image]

And I have tried the following code:

```css
.liContainer {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<li class="liContainer">
  <div>
    <h3>Container 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="id">
    <span>90b5bb870feb5a1148e4f9042f87c957043b71d60dc91d743bccdc5a10c0f54f </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    State:<span class="state">Running</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`word-break:break-all`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) - this allows the line to break between any two letters

See demo below:

```css
.liContainer {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<li class="liContainer">
  <div>
    <h3>Container 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="id">
    <span>90b5bb870feb5a1148e4f9042f87c957043b71d60dc91d743bccdc5a10c0f54f </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    State:<span class="state">Running</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed !! Thank you so much ! (I need to wait 12min before mark your answer as true)